# find all the negative numbers in the array using array_map php

Tags: php, arrays, callback, array-map

I have this test array

```
$test = array(-10,20,40,-30,50,-60);
```

I want the output to be

```
$out = array (-10, -30, -60);
```

Here's my solution:

```
$temp = array();

function neg($x)
{
    if ($x <0) 
    {
        $temp[] = $x; 
        return $x;
    }
}
$negative = array_map("neg", $test);
```

when I print `$negative`, I get what I wanted but with some entries that are null. Is there anything I can do in the callback function to not log the null entries?

```
Array
(
    [0] => -10
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => -30
    [4] => 
    [5] => -60
)
1
```

When I print the `$temp` array, I thought I would get my answer but it printed an empty array. I don't understand why, I'm clearing adding the `$x` to the `$temp[]` array in my callback function. Any thoughts?

```
print_r($temp);
// outputs
Array
(
)
1
```

Comment: you don't want array_map... you want array_filter

Comment: @Orangepill however it's not the concern with array_map right? I'm storing my value $x in a $temp array that is accessible within the callback function.

Comment: See Example [here](https://3v4l.org/CidVl)

Comment: The scope of `$temp` is with in the callback.

Comment: why is it so? I declared the $temp outside my callback and I'm appending $x to $temp everytime the callback is called.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_map` will return the `value` when the condition satisfies and return `NULL` if conditions fails. In this case you can use `array_filter`.

```
$test = array(-10,20,40,-30,50,-60);

$neg = array_filter($test, function($x) {
    return $x < 0;
});
```

**Output**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(-10)
  [3]=>
  int(-30)
  [5]=>
  int(-60)
}
```

And if you continue to use `array_map` then I would suggest apply `array_filter` once when it is done -

```
$negative = array_map("neg", $test);
$negative = array_filter($negative);
```

The output will be same.

Comment: This is great, answers one of my questions, but why the $temp array is not getting populated in my callback function?

Comment: `$temp` is only available inside the function because of the scope. You can't access them like that. Though the `$temp` is no needed anyway.